# Java file automatically overwrites?

Tags: java, file, yaml

I am trying to only create a file if an older version doesn't exist.

This is what I have that I believe is overwriting it:

```
warningsFile = new File(plugin.getDataFolder(), "Warnings.yml");
warnings = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(warningsFile);
```

This is in a constructor, for a secondary class (not main). Whenever the server is reloaded (this is for a server) it appears to execute new File and overwrite. Is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

```
warningsFile = new File(plugin.getDataFolder(), "Warnings.yml");

if(!warningsFile.exists()) {
    try {
        warningsFile.createNewFile();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Bukkit.getServer().getConsoleSender().sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Couldn't create warnings.yml. Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

warnings = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(warningsFile);
```

- First, we instantiate an instance of File. If the file doesn't exist,
  we try to create it.
- If that fails, we tell the console.
- Finally, we
  load the YAML configuration from that file.

This video I made might help:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=_Rntj7r8jTQ

Comment: I originally had just new File(); wouldn't new File(), as your are doing above, create the file?

Comment: No. The `File` class, as Oracle's JavaDocs say, is `an abstract representation of file and directory pathnames`. You could instantiate a `File` with a nonexistant path and it would still work. However, if you tried to `listFiles()` of a folder and the folder didn't exist, it obviously wouldn't work.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Answer (score 0):

(Knowing of this server implementation)

You can simply call:

```
plugin.saveResource("warnings.yml", false);
```

This will load a saved warnings.yml from inside your jarfile (you'll need to put one there), and the `false` specifies to not overwrite the file.